# Autonomous Navigation Algorithm for Robot without know the map

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i want to ask something about the algorithm, can we navigate the robot without know the map first? (I use LIDAR)
I read about amcl, amcl is for estimate the robot, and amcl should know the map first, right?

There is any instruction that i should use ?
and what is the name of method/algorithm behind it?
like amcl is for adaptive monte carlo localization.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336852/autonomous-navigation-algorithm-for-robot-without-know-the-map/) by [billynugrahas](https://answers.ros.org/users/48876/billynugrahas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2019-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See ROS package explore_lite: http://wiki.ros.org/explore_lite

---

Originally posted by [jordan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20512/jordan/) with karma: 125 on 2019-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1